# Why am I getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" despite referencing the library in eclipse and specifying the dependency in build.gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

The error gets thrown for org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveInputStream as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEfgx.png).

I have referenced this library in eclipse (as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bas7q.png))

The dependency has also been specified in build.gradle. The contents of the gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.spongepowered.plugin' version '0.9.0'
}

group = pluginGroup
version = pluginVersion

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21'
}

sponge.plugin.id = pluginId
```

Eclipse also does not flag any errors. Lines of code such as `tarInput.getNextTarEntry()` appear in the correct colour with no red underlining, and eclipse even autocompletes the names of methods found in commons-compress.

Given eclipse *seems* to be working correctly with the dependency, and given that running `./gradlew build` leads to a successful build, I am therefore at a loss for why I am getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError happens at runtime, so how are you launching your application? Also, are you using the Buildship plug-ins for integrating Gradle into Eclipse?

Comment: I run ./gradlew build in my project directory. I am not using Buildship.

Answer (score 1):

@nitind helped. I focused upon runtime and found the problem was to do with my build.gradle file (even though the build was successful!). I changed it to this and the error has vanished:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                mavenCentral()
                }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.spongepowered.plugin' version '0.9.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

group = pluginGroup
version = pluginVersion

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21'
}

jar {
        from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }
}

sponge.plugin.id = pluginId
```